# Wire a new light where there was previously a ceiling fan with a light wired into a 3 gang switch box

Tags: wiring, lighting

[image: kitchen switches][image: kitchen box]
The first switch is a 2 way for the hallway.  The 2nd switch is for the eating area of the kitchen, the 3rd switch is the issue.  It is in the working area of the kitchen and had a light with a fan.  We want to replace it with just a new light fixture.  There are 3 black wires and 3 white wires that were connected to the old fixture.  There is a red wire that is not used here.  One of the black wires remains hot when this light switch is turned off and if not used none of the lights work.  How do I connect the new light so it will work with the switch and shut off?  The hall light and eating area switches are in the on position in the photo so I could take the photos.

Comment: To clarify the last part.  One of the black wires remains hot when the switch is turned off so the light won't shut off using the switch.  How do we rewire so the three lights will work using the 3 switches as above.

Comment: Was the third switch used to control the fan and light together? Also, was the third switch connected to the common black used by the other switches before you started work?

Comment: Is the diagram you've drawn intended to show what you want or what you have? It doesn't seem to correspond with your description...

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the light in question?

Comment: The third switch was used to control the light and the fan worked off the chain attached as there was always power to it.  The 3 black wires were connected together to work all three lights before we took the fan down. I'm attaching actual photos but not sure how well they show up. Above was just to show the 3 switch  set up.

Comment: @DIYer, you can't put attachments in comments, but you can edit your original question to include attachments and as much extra info as possible.  I understand you as saying you have 3 black wires, 3 white wires and a red wire in the box in the ceiling after you removed the fixture. Which wires are currently twisted together and do the switches to the other lights currently operate?

Comment: @octopus.  Thank you for your assistance.  I added the actual photos and updated the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Was everything working correctly before you removed the fan? All you want to do is replace the fan with a light fixture? If you have everything wired the way it was when everything was working and you removed the fan you should now have three wires. One white and I'm guessing from your description two blacks. One of those blacks provided continuous power to the fan so it would always operate whether the switch was on or not. You won't need that wire, put a wire nut on it. You should now have a black and a white left, those will connect to the black and white on the new light fixture. If I misunderstood or if you mixed the wires up then you may want to post a better picture of the ceiling box without the bracket as it's hard to see where the wires come from.

Comment: @ platinum goose or anyone else.  The box has 3 main wires coming into it.  The top one contains a black and white wire.  The left one contains a black, white and red wire.  The red wire was capped off when the fan was hooked up.  The right one has the hot black wire and a white wire.  If we cap off the hot black wire and connect the rest of the black and white wires we get no power to any of the 3 lights. No idea what the red wire is for!  Any thoughts?

Comment: You just lost me. If all three blacks were connected and the red was capped off then what three wires were connected to the fan when it was working?

Comment: As far as I remember it was just all the black and white wires.  The red wire has no power itself when the switch is on.  ow should these be connected?

Comment: Does the switch have power at one of the terminals? What color wires are connected to the switch?

Comment: There is a red wire and a black wire connected to the switch for the kitchen light, a black , red and white connected to the 2 way hall switch and two black wires connected the to the eating area switch.

Comment: Lets focus on the red and the black connected to the kitchen switch,do they exit the kitchen box or are they connected to other wires in the box? If they exit the box do they exit along with a white wire. What I'm trying to get at is if the red, black and white in the ceiling box go to the kitchen box.

Comment: Turns out all we had to do was connect the black wire from the new light to the red wire in the box and the white wire to the other white wires.  The black wires in the box were all connected and left separate, not used for the new light fixture.  All works well now.